# A Unresolved attribute reference sert' for class 'object'

Tags: python, pycharm, streamlit

I am working in pycharm in Streamlit. My code is working correctly on Jupyter Notebook but Pycharm  is giving the following error:

> Unresolved attribute reference 'insert' for class 'object'
> Unresolved attribute reference 'sort' for class 'object'

Errors are occurring only for `country` variable not for `year`.
The code is here:

```
import numpy as np
def country_year_list(df):
    years = df['Year'].unique().tolist()
    years.sort()
    years = years.insert(0, 'Overall')

    # Create a list of countries
    country = np.unique(df['region'].dropna().values).tolist()

    # Sort the list
    country.sort()

    # Insert a new item at the beginning of the list
    country.insert(0, 'Overall')

    return years, country
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing in PyCharm is related to the `country` list variable. The error message "Unresolved attribute reference 'sort' for class 'object'" suggests that PyCharm is not recognizing `country` as a list object, but rather as a generic `object` type.
I think that PyCharm is not able to correctly infer the type of the `country` variable. Remember that PyCharm requires explicit type annotations to be added to the code.
You can add a type annotation to the `country` variable. I tried to rewrite the code by myself-

```
from typing import List

def country_year_list(df) -> Tuple[List[str], List[str]]:
    years = df['Year'].unique().tolist()
    years.sort()
    years = years.insert(0, 'Overall')

    country: List[str] = np.unique(df['region'].dropna().values).tolist()

    country.sort()

     country.insert(0, 'Overall')

    return years, country
```

I have imported the `List` type from the `typing` module and used it to annotate the `country` variable as a list of strings. Please, feel free to ask if you have any doubt!